# Mongoose -- Force collection name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, collections

I am trying to use `mongoose` to create a database and a collection in it. My code is:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserInfo = new Schema({
  username : String,
  password : String 
});

mongoose.model('UserInfo', UserInfo);

var user = db.model('UserInfo');

var admin = new user();
admin.username = "sss";
admin.password = "ee";
admin.save();
```

When I run this code, mongoose created collection named `UserInfo` instead of `userinfo`.
How to force collection name in mongoose?

Comment: Fun fact: mongoose knows that the plural of ox is oxen, but not that the plural of goose is geese.

Answer (score 260):

This should do it

```
var UserInfo = new Schema({
  username : String,
  password : String 
}, { collection: 'userinfo' });
```

See [this link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection) from the Mongoose documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks for this. Here's the relevant link: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection

Comment: Thanks @JonPage, I was wondering why my collection of Person objects was named as people.  The link you provided is a good reference.  I think this method of setting a custom collection name when creating a schema is better than the other method of defining a collection name when creating the model.

Comment: This was super helpful.  I spent two days trying to query something now.

Answer (score 106):

If you are using mongoose 2.0.0, pass the collectionName as the third argument

```
mongoose.model('UserInfo', UserInfo, 'UserInfo');
```

Comment: Perfect way to declare a custom collection name at the model's level.

Comment: This answer doesn't say if this is still working until 2.0.0 or if it has been implemented since 2.0.0.

Answer (score 38):

Mongoose will add 's' to collection name by default. If you want to avoid that, just pass as third argument the name of the collection:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserInfo = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String 
});

mongoose.model('UserInfo', UserInfo, 'UserInfo')

tan = new user();
admin.username = 'sss';
admin.password = 'ee';
admin.save();
```

Comment: This is the best suggestion. I have always found it the easiest to just pass the collection name in mongoose.model(). Also good for pointing out how mongoose pluralizes the collection name, that was confusing when I first started.

Comment: Mongoose will auto convert the `model` name to a `collection` name with `s` by default.

Answer (score 17):

API structure of mongoose.model is this:

```
Mongoose#model(name, [schema], [collection], [skipInit])
```

What mongoose do is that, When no collection argument is passed, Mongoose produces a collection name by pluralizing the model name. If you don't like this behavior, either pass a collection name or set your schemas collection name option.

Example:

```
var schema = new Schema({ name: String }, { collection: 'actor' });
```

or

```
schema.set('collection', 'actor');
```

or

```
var collectionName = 'actor'
var M = mongoose.model('Actor', schema, collectionName);
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to set the collection name in your schema.

```
new Schema({...},{collection: 'userInfo'});
```

Answer (score 9):

Mongoose maintainer here. We recommend doing `mongoose.model('UserInfo', UserInfo, 'UserInfo');`, third arg to `mongoose.model()` is the collection name. [Here's the relevant docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-model).

Answer (score 8):

Passing a third argument on `module.exports = mongoose.model('name', schema, 'collection')` overrides the automatic collection name based on model name, which has already been answered.. but there are 2 other ways,

per mongoose.model doco link:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-model

there are 3 methods to manually enter a collection name:

```
var schema = new Schema({ name: String }, { collection: 'actor' });

// or

schema.set('collection', 'actor');

// or

var collectionName = 'actor'
var M = mongoose.model('Actor', schema, collectionName)
```

Answer (score 5):

**Answer:**

```
mongoose.model('UserInfo', UserInfo, 'userinfo'); //3rd parameter 'userinfo': as collection name
```

> Better explanation with syntax:

```
Mongoose.model(name, [schema], [collection], [skipInit])
```

Parameters Explanation:

- 1st parameter - name  model name
- 2nd parameter [schema]  schema name
- 3rd parameter [collection]  collection name (optional, induced from model name)
- 4th parameter [skipInit]  whether to skip initialization (defaults to false)

Answer (score 0):

your model name : userInfo.js

in express route file or app.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb');
```

then in your userInfo.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserInfo = new Schema({
 username : String,
 password : String 
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserInfo', UserInfo);
```