# Mongoose always returning an empty array NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have tried using `find` and `findOne` and both are not returning a document. `find` is returning an empty array while `findOne` is returning `null`. `err` in both cases in `null` as well.

Here is my connection:

```
function connectToDB(){
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test"); //i have also tried 127.0.0.1
    db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
    db.once("open", function callback(){
        console.log("CONNECTED");
    });
};
```

Here is my schema:

```
var fileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    hash: String,
    type: String,
    extension: String,
    size: String,
    uploaded: {type:Date, default:(Date.now)},
    expires: {type:Date, default:(Date.now()+oneDay)}
});
var Model = mongoose.model("Model", fileSchema);
```

And my query is here:

```
Model.find({},function(err, file) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(file);  
});
```

I can upload things to the database and see them via [RockMongo](http://rockmongo.com/) but I cannot fetch them after. This my first time using MongoDB so I think I'm just missing some of the fundamentals. Any push in the right direction would be great!

Comment: What the name of the collection you're seeing documents in via RockMongo?

Comment: All the info is in a collection `files` under test

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The call to `mongoose.model` establishes the name of the collection the model is tied to, with the default being the [pluralized](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection), lower-cased model name.  So with your code, that would be `'models'`.  To use the model with the `files` collection, change that line to:

```
var Model = mongoose.model("Model", fileSchema, "files");
```

or

```
var Model = mongoose.model("file", fileSchema);
```

Comment: Saved the day. Thanks a lot! It's a pity this is not highlighted in the official guide.

Comment: @thameera same here. I'm moving into uncharted waters from .net land and I wasted so much time on this one. Lifesaver. Yea, convention does not seemed to be mentioned _anywhere_, at least in my search attempts. Thank you!!!

Comment: I found this out the hard way too -- that model("object",...) actually creates a collection called "objects".  ORMs that are a bit too magical, but fortunately there's Stack Overflow!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486528/mongoose-force-collection-name

Answer (score 3):

Simply inorder to avoid pluralization complexity use this:

```
var Model = mongoose.model("Model", fileSchema, "pure name your db collection");
```

It's very confusing.[at least for me.]

Answer (score 1):

Had kinda same problem. The solutions above didnt work for me. My app never returns error even if the query is not found. It returns empty array. So i put this in my code:

```
if(queryResult.length==0) return res.status(404).send("not found");
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is probably coming from the fact that you are creating a **mongoose model** without specifying the **name of the collection**.

Try changing : `const Model = mongoose.model("Model", fileSchema);`

To this : `const Model = mongoose.model("Model", fileSchema, "NameOfCollection");`

Answer (score 0):

```
const growingUnit= mongoose.model('Growing Unit', growingUnitSchema);
```

I had a space in 'Growing Unit' on purpose and it always returned empty array. Removing that space to become 'GrowingUnit' was the fix needed in my scenario.

```
const growingUnit= mongoose.model('Growing Unit', growingUnitSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

**General "hello world" issues** (Sometimes this issue not related to mongoose).

1. Check if the **collection** is not **really** empty ([mongoDB atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) screenshot).

[image]

2. Check for small spelling differences (Like `listing` instead of `listings`) in your collection queries commands.
3. Check if you use the correct `URI` for your connection (For example you are trying to retrieve data from a collection that exists in `localhost` but use `mongoDB cluster` (Cloud) -or- any other issue related to Connection String URI).
   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was `.skip(value)`, I was passing `page=1` instead of `page=0`.
As I was having few records, I was getting empty array always.