# How to query data in MongoDB using Mongoose in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a node.js REST API and i cannot query data in my API> here's the link to my code on github. [Github line 150](https://github.com/chanakaDe/Mint-REST/blob/master/app/routes/api.js)

And alo this is the code example

```
  api.get('/story', function (req, res) {
    Story.find({owner: req.decoded._id}, function (err, stories) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            return
        }
        res.json(stories);
    });
});
```

I want to find all the Stories creatd by logged user. o i send the user id in request. there are many posts done by user, but i'm getting a null array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183611/mongoose-always-returning-an-empty-array-nodejs. Can you check that first?

Comment: I think I have a different error here. Please check my code and then you will understand that. In line 99 , I have written a same method and it return me data. But other method in line 150 , its always getting empty array. Here's the link. https://github.com/chanakaDe/Mint-REST/blob/master/app/routes/api.js

Answer (score 0):

Use Mongoose debugging

`var mongoose = require('mongoose').set('debug', true)`

then look at your database request at nodejs console and debug it into mongodb console

check datatypes (string/ObjectId), check if it sends null as "owner"

Answer (score 0):

You have written the same GET api `api.get('/story',function(){});` twice with different logics. This is the cause for the output. Because the api written in line 99 will get called always when there is `/story` api call.