# document object returning null when querying in mongodb using express + node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm new to using express, node.js, and mongodb. I've been trying to access a specific document to display in the front-end, but data only returns null.

**db.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const BusinessSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    tags: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    }
});

const businessModel = mongoose.model("Businesses", BusinessSchema);
module.exports = businessModel;
```

**main.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Businesses = require('../models/Businesses');

router.get('', async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await Businesses.findOne({ name: 'The Board and Brew' });
    res.render('index', {data});
  } catch (error){
    console.log(error);
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

My connection to the database seems to be working, so I'm not sure where the issue lies. I'm super new to web dev so thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Can you do `const data = await Businesses.find({})` to see all documents and check if the one with `name: 'The Board and Brew'` is actually in there? Also, what is `router.get('')` ? Where is the router mounted?

Comment: i got it! due to mongoose looking for pluralized, lower-case version mongoose.model was looking for a collection named 'businessess'. my collection was named Businesses, so i just changed the last line of db.js to const businessModel = mongoose.model("Business", BusinessSchema, "Businesses"). [This post helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183611/mongoose-always-returning-an-empty-array-nodejs)