# Is there a way to prevent MongoDB adding plural form to collection names?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

It all works fine until I want to create a collection named 'Mice' for example. Both Mouses and Mices are unacceptable. Would be good if there is an option to set this in the config.
Comments: thanks for the suggestion, I am using Mongoose.

Comment: What do you mean? Where does MongoDB do this? I have never known this functionality

Comment: Perhaps you could specify the ODM you are using, since it is that which is adding the plural names. And there usually will be a way to fix that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongoose -- Force collection name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486528/mongoose-force-collection-name)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you name your model 'mouse', Mongoose will actually pluralize the collection name correctly to 'mice' (see [source code](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/utils.js#L31)).

But you can also explicitly name your collection when creating a model by passing it as the third parameter to [`model`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model):

```js
var Mice = mongoose.model('Mice', MouseSchema, 'Mice');
```

Answer (score 4):

API structure of mongoose.model is this:
Mongoose#model(name, [schema], [collection], [skipInit])

What mongoose do is that, When no collection argument is passed, Mongoose produces a collection name by pluralizing the model name. If you don't like this behavior, either pass a collection name or set your schemas collection name option.

Example

var schema = new Schema({ name: String }, { collection: 'actor' });

// or

schema.set('collection', 'actor');

// or

var collectionName = 'actor'
var M = mongoose.model('Actor', schema, collectionName);

For more information check this link:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, How you can understand how mongoose produce pluralize forms

```
function pluralize(str) {
  var found;
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  if (!~uncountables.indexOf(str)) {
    found = rules.filter(function(rule) {
      return str.match(rule[0]);
    });
    if (found[0]) {
      return str.replace(found[0][0], found[0][1]);
    }
  }
  return str;
}
```

Reference Link: https://github.com/vkarpov15/mongoose-legacy-pluralize/blob/master/index.js