# could not find anything on my mongodb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got a strange behaviur using mongoose. I got empty array, but my document have some document. This is my Account.js :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var accountSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    cover: String,
    createAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    subscriber_email: String
});

var Account = module.exports = mongoose.model('account', accountSchema);

module.exports = Account;
```

This is my controller, the filename is home.js

```
var User = require('../models/User');
var Account = require('../models/Account');

exports.getNumberOfAccounts = function(req, res) {
    Account.find({}, function(err,response){
        console.log(response)
    });
}
```

How I can it in server.js

```
var app = express();
var homeController = require('./controllers/home');
app.post('/getNumberOfAccounts', homeController.getNumberOfAccounts);
```

Which part I've done wrong? I always get empty array.

Comment: The names and types of attrubutes in accountSchema are equals in the database?

Comment: @LucasCosta yes

Comment: try this `mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema);`

Comment: are you sure that your collection `Account` has documents?

Comment: @abdulbarik yes

Comment: @ZeRubeus my document's name is account not Account.

Comment: Can you try to export directly your model instead of setting in variable like this `module.exports = mongoose.model('account', accountSchema);` and then try

Comment: @abdulbarik doesn't make any different

Comment: Maybe try inserting a new entry by using .save() and see if there's a difference in the database. And also test if the newly inserted data can be retrieved.

Comment: @Tyratox can. I'm pissed I spent 3 hours couldn't solve this, not sure it's a bug of moongose or what.

Comment: @MariaJane Yeahh it seems strange

Comment: @Tyratox I delete the schema and I change the 'account' to 'photos' i can get the data, I'm seriously stuck now.

Comment: I renamed my document from account to accounts and it worked, stupid mongodb auto pural feature

Comment: @MariaJane WTF, didn't think Mongoose would do that! If you want to stick to a singular form, you can take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22394469/2897827

Comment: Stupid moongse feature, stuck for 5 hours!!!