# Is there anything wrong with my mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've stuck for 3 hours wrong and couldn't solve this issue. I'm getting nothing from my document.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var accountSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    salt: String,
    hash: String,
    cover: String,
    createAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    subscriber_email: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('account', accountSchema);
```

I tested with other schema they all worked but not this one. My data's like below

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really get what the issue is here

Comment: @Tyratox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933718/could-not-find-anything-on-my-mongodb-database

Comment: What is the problem you are stuck at? Please elaborate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you are not able to view anything in your document is the way you are exporting the `accountSchema`.

Try replacing `Account` with `account` while exporting the `schema`.

**Try this:**

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema);
```

Everything else looks fine.

I hope this helps.