# Declare collection name without s in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Trying to create collection name without last name s but default in s is added with collection name in mongodb.So how to avoid s with collection name.

data.controller.model.js:

```
   var NewModel = require(path.resolve('./models/data.model.js'))(collectionname);
   NewModel.create({}, function(err, doc) {  });
```

data.model.js:

```
/* model.js */
'use strict'; 
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema; 
function dynamicModel(suffix) {
    var collsName = suffix.toLowerCase();
    var newSchema = new Schema({ 
        product_name: {
            type: String
        } 
    }, { collection: collsName }); 
    return mongoose.model(suffix, newSchema); 
} 
module.exports = dynamicModel;
```

Comment: Does this answer you question https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection

Comment: also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391706/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-mongodb-adding-plural-form-to-collection-names/24464105