# the name in mongoose.model function is not same as collection name in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This strange problem. I use mongoose to create a schema and model and ,then save something into database. Because this is a new collections. mongodb create the collection automatical. But I find that the collections name is diffrent to the definiton in mongoose model function.

Example:
In Script:
  chessMD = mogoose.model("chessDB",chessSchema);

but in mongodb client
  After I use show collections, the collection name is chessdbs;

anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Mongoose will automatically create a collection name by pluralizing the name of the model. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model

If however you want to force a specific collection name you can do that too. See [Mongoose -- Force collection name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486528/mongoose-force-collection-name) for answers.