# Save document to specific collection in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble trying understand which is the collection I'm saving the document to. I have the following piece of code:

```
var message = mongoose.Schema({
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var message_temp = mongoose.model('message', message);
```

Now what can I do to save that message to a specific collection? If I do

```
 message.save(function(err){});
```

Where is the message actually kept?

Comment: Connect to the mongod instance you are using by the mongo shell, issue `use <yourDataBase>` and `show collections`.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg But what can I do to save that message to a specific collection?

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7722490/1296707

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Markus if you could please take a look at my other questions related to mongodb, you seem to be the only guy that answers. See [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635844/define-collection-after-model) speciffically please, tyvm!

Answer (score 13):

To define a collection you just need to:

```
var message_temp = mongoose.model('message', message,'collectionyouwant');
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `message` model once compiled. The question as I see was about temporary (dynamic) sending request to db to specific collection

Comment: Being March 2020 this is not in the mongoose docs, unbelievable... Thanks for the answer works with mongoose 5.9.6

Comment: Not sure since when it was there, but as of March 2021 this is the [model documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-model). Good catch though.

Answer (score 5):

Im six years late, but some people might still find this useful.
Per docs, you specify the collection like this when saving a model, { collection: 'name' }

Like this:

```
 const model = new Model({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        somefield: "some value",
        someotherfield: "some other value"
    }, { collection: 'here you put the name of your collection' });
```

link to docs
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection

Answer (score 0):

**i think this will help you**

*creating collection schema and collection*

```
// creating schema(bluepring) for collection(table)

const userSchema = {
    email: String,
    password: String
};
//creating collection of schema
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

***creating object document to store in collection***

```
const newUser = new User({//newUser is the document object we want to store
            email: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        });
```

*saving document into collection*

```
 newUser.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.error(err);
            }
            else{
                console.log("data added successfully");
                
            }
        });
```

**hope you like it if there is something wrong in my explaination and code than please point it out**