# nodejs , mongo find return no data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to get list of the data from mongodb using find() and although I do have data at the collection, it returns no data! I can't figure out what the reason is, can anyone help?

result like : 
{
error: false,
massage: [ ]
}

this is the project **Dependencies**

```
 "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-handlebars": "^3.1.0",
        "mongoose": "^5.8.3",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
   }
```

**server.js**

```js
require('./models/db');

const express = require('express');

const loController = require('./controllers/loController');

var app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('I am Listening ... ');
});

app.use('/lomanager', loController);
```

**db.js**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/LOManager', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (error) => {
    if (!error) console.log('mongoose connection success');
    else console.log("error with mongo connnect" + error);
});

require('./lo.model');
```

**lo.model.js**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var loSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String,
    email: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('LO', loSchema);
```

**loController.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
var loSchema = require('../models/lo.model');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json('helo from lo Controller');
});

router.get('/list', (req, res) => {
    var result = {};
    loSchema.find({}, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            result = { "error": true, "message": "error in the find" }
        } else {
            result = { "error": false, "massage": data };
        }
        res.json(result);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204775/discussion-on-question-by-h-h-nodejs-mongo-find-return-no-data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your collection name is **'LO'** so please use that code

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('LO', loSchema,'LO');
```

Answer (score 0):

that happened because Mongoose pluralizes the collection name by default

so we can also do it like that:

```
var loSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String,
    email: String
} , {collection: 'LO'});


module.exports = mongoose.model('LO', loSchema);
```

this link explained why!
[mongoose-force-collection-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486528/mongoose-force-collection-name)