# $lookup using mongoose Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using Nodejs(express) using Mongoose to connect with MongoDB.
Here two collections which where created using Mongoose schema in other API calls. For one API call request,  i need to join these two collections and create the new collection (testalluser)which contains the new consolidated output.
And need to find all documents and send the output in the response to API call.

Note: I tried creating the Model also , but it not worked.

Query working fine inside DB .But in Mongoose, I am getting only empty array as the output .could you please help me to apply this logic in to Mongoose in NodeJS.

```
db.getallusers.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "getallusersroles",
      "localField": "userRefID",
      "foreignField": "userRefID",
      "as": "role"
    }
  },
  
{ $merge: { into: "testalluser" } }

]).pretty()
```

**Collection 1 Schema:getAllUsers**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const getAllUsersDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    userRefID:String ,
    userName:String,
    divisionId: String,
    divisionName:String,
    emailId :String,

})

module.exports = getAllUsers = mongoose.model('getAllUsers',getAllUsersDataSchema );
```

**Collection 2 getAllUsersRoles**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const getAllUsersRolesDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    userRefID:String ,
    skillRefId: String,
    queueName:String,

})

module.exports = getAllUsersRoles = mongoose.model('getAllUsersRoles',getAllUsersRolesDataSchema);
```

**Collection 3: testalluser(i Tried but i am not sure its needed)**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const getAllCustomUsersDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    
    divisionId: String,
    divisionName:String,
    emailId :String,
    role: Array,
    userRefID:String ,
    userName:String,

})

module.exports = testalluser = mongoose.model('testalluser',getAllCustomUsersDataSchema);
```

**NodeJs Code:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');
const config = require('../config');
const fs = require('fs'); 
const getAllUsers = require ('../db/getAllUsersListmodel');
const getAllUsersRoles = require ('../db/getetUserRolesListModel');
const testalluser =require('../db/getCustomUserListModel');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect ('mongodb://localhost/testdb',{ useUnifiedTopology: true , useNewUrlParser: true });

 
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // token in session -> get user data and send it back to the Angular app
   
  // Empty up the already existing documents inside this collection
testalluser.deleteMany({},()=>{  

//Here i am trying to aggregate 
   getAllUsers.aggregate([
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "getallusersroles",
          "localField": "userRefID",
          "foreignField": "userRefID",
          "as": "role"
        }
      },
      
    { $merge: { into: "testalluser" } } // creating this doc first time
    
    ]).

    // Here i am trying to find the docs in this newly created collection
    testalluser.find((err,getusers)=>{
      if(err){
      console.log(err)
      }
      else{ 
        res.send(getusers);
        console.log(getusers);
      }
   })  
    
  })
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

Comment: The `from` field in the `$lookup` needs to be the collection name as seen by MongoDB.  In the first pipeline you used `"getallusersroles"`, in the second `"getAllUsersRoles"`.  Typo?

Comment: @Joe Yes its typo, i corrected now. But i verified earlier if i am using the correct naming convention also , no desired output coming.

Comment: I think the default collection name for that model will be `testallusers`, if you want to force it to be `testalluser`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7527515/2282634