# mongoose doesn't allow me to use camelCase collection name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Here is my code:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/miniRDS", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}, (err) => {
    if(!err){
        console.log("Connected")
    }else{
        console.log("Couldn't connect!");
    }
});

const tests = new mongoose.Schema({
    subject: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: "ict"
    },
    date: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: "01-01-2021"
    }
});

const testsModel = mongoose.model("classTests", tests);
const s = new testsModel({
    subject: "english",
    date: "12-01-2021"
});

s.save();
```

---

I am using mongoose version 5.11.11. And I am facing difficulty when I try to create a collection with camelCase name using mongoose model.

In the above codes, It should create a collection name "classTests", instead it creates "classtests".  how can I achieve "classTests"? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8269

Comment: just add collection name in schema second parameter, i have already added in your another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672645/8987128)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use it as:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("user_notification_preference", NotificationPreference, "userNotificationPreferences");
```

three parameters:(the name you want to use as camel, schema, the actual name)

Answer (score 3):

## Solution :

#### To Resolve this, We can use a Plural name in the `collection` field

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const AssessmentAttemptSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
    },
    verificationToken: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    collection: 'assessmentAttempts',
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('AssessmentAttempt', AssessmentAttemptSchema);
```

So for this case, we are using `assessmentAttempts` to save the collection name as CamelCase.

End Result:
[Mongo DB : Sample Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9UD3.png)

MongoDB Collection Name Restrictions Docs : [Reference Link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#naming-restrictions)

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased version of your model name,
please check this [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html), so you can't create a collection with camelCase in mongoose