# Collection returning empty when trying to findAll(). RESTful and Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to implement a RESTful API using REST, NodeJS, ExpressJS and MongoDB atlas. I have sucessfully connected my atlas database and I am trying to retrieve everything from the collection "personal_information".

My atlas cloud collection looks like this:

```
_id:ObjectId("60884283fd31d723047c6f7c")
customerID:"6543524356"
Title:"Ms"
Fname:"Anna"
Lname:"Dunne"
mobile:"0764323456"
email:"anna@here.ie"
```

My server.js connects successfully to my cloud database

My model.js looks like this:

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// create a mongoose schema for a quotation
const PersonalInfoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   customerID: String,
   Title: String,
   Fname: String,
   Lname: String,
   mobile: String,
   email: String
  },  {
    timestamps: true
 });
 // export the model to our app
  module.exports = mongoose.model('Personal_information', PersonalInfoSchema);
```

here is the portion of my controller.js that is suppose to find all documents in my personal_information

```
  exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
     Personal_information.find()
       .then(personal_information => {
           res.send(personal_information);
        }).catch(err => {
           res.status(500).send({
               message: err.message || "An error occurred while retrieving all personal information."
           });
       });
};
```

I have defined the route as

```
    module.exports = (app) => {
       app.get('/personal_information', personal_information.findAll);
     }
```

but when I run the url in postman, it returns empty, even though I have 3 documents in my personal_information collection. Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Comment: Is the server.js connecting to the right database?

Comment: @Joe yep, its connecting to the correct database

Comment: The collection is named 'personal_informations'?

Comment: It is named "personal_information"

Comment: Try explicitly setting that as the collection name.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7527515/2282634